# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^x}{x}$ with Euler's formula?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to solve this limit?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^x}{x}$$

Wolfram Alpha said that the answer is $0$.

But I think that it has no limit. What I tried is

$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{(-1)^x}{x} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{e^{i\pi x}}{x} 
\end{align}$

I have no idea how to get $0$ from that, because it looks like undefined $$(\frac{\infty}{\infty})$$

Or, I have another perspective like this:

$\begin{align}\text{Let}\, \dfrac{(-1)^x}{x}&=L\\
\ln L &= \ln \left(\dfrac{e^{i\pi x}}{x}\right)\\
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\ln L &= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\ln \left(\dfrac{e^{i\pi x}}{x}\right)\\
&=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}i\pi x - \ln x\\
&=\infty - 0\\
&=\infty
\end{align}$

Thus

$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\ln L&=\infty\\
L=0
\end{align}$

I don't know if it's right or not. Please do a correction. Thanks.

Comment: Observe that $|e^{i\theta}|=1$ for any $\theta$.

Comment: @GReyes: For any real $\theta$.

Comment: Right. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: In the last, if $L=0$, then $\ln L=-\infty$ not $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just use an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.  Choose $\epsilon \gt 0$.  Let $N = \lceil \frac 1\epsilon \rceil.$  Then $x \gt N \Rightarrow \lvert \frac{(-1)^x}{x} \rvert = \lvert \frac 1x \rvert \lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The number is bounded between -1 and 1 while the denominator approaches $\infty$. Hence, the limit must be zero (although it does not approach $0$ monotonically).

Comment: Be careful. When $x$ is not an integer, $(-1)^x$ is a (multivalued) complex number, but any of their magnitudes will be $1$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Yes indeed. Thank you. I presumed the question pertained to real variables only.

Comment: Yes, but remember that $a^x = e^{x\log a}$, and it's only because $a=-1$ that all the values of $\log a$ are purely imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

For  an arbitrary real number $x$, $(-1)^{x}$ is not well defined.

For example if you let $x=1/24$ then you will have $24$ complex roots of $-1$

In order to make sense out of the question we need to modify it into a sequence  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {(-1)^n}{n}$$ in which case it is zero because its absolute value goes to $0$

Comment: Modified into a sequnce?

Comment: Correct, that is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You got the correct result, but I don't agree with your working.

**Hint:**

I would split this into two cases, $x=2k$, and $x=2k+1$. With this, you can better evaluate $(-1)^x$ to find the limit of both cases to be equal.

Comment: Why are you assuming that $x$ is an integer?

Answer (score 0):

If we think of it as the limit of sequence
$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$
so, in fact, it is equal to $0$, since
$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|=\frac{1}{n}$$
and the last can be made as small as one wishes, for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Hmmm... so it use absolute convergence test?

Comment: No. It use the definition of the limit of a sequence, that is, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that, for all $n\geq N$ we have $|a_n-0|<\varepsilon$.